# How to plot a graph of a custom surface in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, 3d, matlab-figure

I would like to plot the surface of this function in Matlab:

```
w=(m*(1-p))/(h-1+m*(1-p))
```

Where

```
h=0.98;
P=[0.05:0.001:0.98];
M=[0:0.001:1];
```

The graph should look like this:

[image]

I tried to implement the graphing function as:

```
h=0.98;
P=[0.05:0.001:0.98];
M=[0:0.001:1];
W=[];
for i=1:size(P, 2)
    for j=1:size(M, 2)
        p=P(i);
        m=M(j);
        w=(m*(1-p))/(h-1+m*(1-p));
        if w>1000
            w=1000;
        end
        if w<0
            w=0;
        end
        W(i, j) = w;
    end
end
mesh(M, P, W);
```

But since the function changes rapidly around the boundary condition, my graph ended up looking like this:

[image]

How can I smooth out the curve and give it a nice, uniform grid like in the first picture?

Comment: In short: [limit the z axis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zlim.html) to 10 when plotting, and I suggest `meshgrid` instead of loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what you want. See comments in the code for more information.

```
%% //Definitions
w = @(h,m,p)(m.*(1-p))./(h-1+m.*(1-p)); %// w as a function handle
w_min = 0; w_max = 10; %// For plots
cMap = hot(200); cMap = cMap(floor(0.5*length(cMap)):ceil(0.7*length(cMap)),:);

h = 0.98;
m_start = 0; m_end = 1; m_step = [0.02 0.01 0.001];
p_start = 0.05; p_end = 0.98; p_step = [0.1 0.01 0.001];
%// Definitions of the mesh used in plotting (same for all charts)
mesh_m_step = 0.05; mesh_p_step = 0.05;
[meshM,meshP] = meshgrid(m_start:mesh_m_step:m_end,p_start:mesh_p_step:p_end);
meshW = w(h,meshM,meshP);
%% //Evaluation and plotting:
figure(); set(gcf,'Position',[240,500,1391,376]); subplot(1,3,1);
for ind1 = 1:3
    %% // Evaluate equation
    [MM,PP] = meshgrid(m_start:m_step(ind1):m_end,p_start:p_step(ind1):p_end);
    WW = w(h,MM,PP);
    %% // Plot
    subplot(1,3,ind1);
    surf(MM,PP,WW,'EdgeColor','none'); view([45,45]); 
    hold on; mesh(meshM,meshP,meshW,'EdgeColor','k','FaceColor','none');        
    colormap(cMap); %// Fix the colormap
    zlim([w_min,w_max]); caxis(zlim) %// Modify zlim
end
```

Which results in:
[image: Approximately what was required]